# Counting the number of conjugated pi bonds in a complex aromatic molecule

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, aromatic-compounds, hyperconjugation

So for multiple bonds to be conjugated, they must be in an alternating
double bond – single bond – double bond, etc arrangement. However, do they need to be continuous? In my textbook, they count the number of conjugated multiple bonds like this:

[image]

However, for other molecules such as 9,10-Bis(phenylethynyl)anthracene :

[image]

Would I count the number of conjugated multiple bonds as a total of 13 or as 7? In other words, do the bonds need to be continuous to be counted as conjugated pi bonds?

Comment: The total number of conjugated double bonds is 13: these bonds form groups of 7,3,3 conjugated bonds each in the anthracene and benzene rings respectively.

Comment: The problem is in the geometry of the molecule. Are the two external phenyl groups coplanar with the anthracen central group ?

Comment: There's **15** conjugated pi bonds there and two perpendicular in triple bonds. What is the point of this question though? Illustration from book is for specific context - dependence of color of compounds with *linear* group of bonds. Other compounds behave quite differently.